# Gesture Recognition does not work when Converting MAUI ContentView to Native UIViewController

Tags: c#, maui, maui-ios

I'm working with a .NET MAUI application and facing an issue when converting a `ContentView` to a native `UIViewController`.

My objective is to use native views while retaining all MAUI features, including gestures.

However, after the conversion, the gesture recognizers attached to the ContentView and children within the ContentView are not working in the resulting `UIViewController`.

The ContentView is not shown and will be shown only after the conversion.

Is there another way to fix this problem to ensure that gesture recognizers work as expected in the converted view?

```
 private static UIViewController ConvertToNativeView(this ContentView contentView)
    {
        var mauiContext = new MauiContext(RbtServiceProvider.Current);
    
        if (contentView.Handler is not ContentViewHandler handler)
        {
            handler = new ContentViewHandler();
            handler.SetMauiContext(mauiContext);
            contentView.Handler = handler;
            handler.SetVirtualView(contentView);
        }
    
        if (handler.MauiContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not convert {nameof(contentView)} to native view");
        }
    
        var uiViewController = contentView.ToUIViewController(mauiContext);
        return uiViewController;
    }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: I am implementing  a native iOS control and need to show my xaml content view inside the native control

Comment: According to the [definition of the ContentView](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/74fbfcbabd4c41256b26c7dcbdcacda32d02fa94/src/Core/src/Platform/iOS/MauiView.cs#L10), it implements `UIView` so you can't convert a `ContentView` to a `UIViewController`.